# game - how can I drag objects (cars with numbers) into targets (start line) AS3.0.?

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, adobe, flash-cs6

I am having this problem, where I have several cars, numbers and letters, and need to put 5 cars in the starting places. -random order is ok.

I' having trouble finding in AS3 a way so that the EndX and EndY of each object can be in the starting lines and be considered right no matter the order!

I'm having trouble putting the code here so, heres a titanpad with the code:

this is the code:
being (um, dois, tres, quatro) the movieclip instance name for each numbered car.
https://titanpad.com/42vtnCbvLu

Comment: Did you go with alternate solution or you still need help with this? First thing is you dont need to repeat the same variables over & over again. the computer knows var `umEndX:int = 113;` if you type it once.. Also you should have kept an array (grouping) of your preffered starting position then use a randomiser function that randomly picks one object and then also picks a random start-pos from the array...

Comment: I called the person and she came to the conclusion that it could be done in another way that was easy for me. either way I simplified it so I didn't had so much code I didn't need! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you could probably benefit by using the distance between two points formula and seeing if the distance is less than a certain value rather than checking in all 4 directions manually:

```
Math.abs(Math.sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2))
```

Let the position of the car  be (x1,y1) and the start position (x2,y2).
This formula will give you the distance between the two points in any direction, and you could test maybe whether this value is less than your offset.

As for the cars in any order part, I'm interpreting that you have your cars and you want the user to drag them to one of 5 spots, a bit like this:

spot1

spot2

spot3

spot4

spot5

All with respective coordinates. My suggestion would be to have a boolean flag for whether each spot is occupied that stops the program checking whether a car is put there after it has been taken once.
Once all these flags are true, then you can proceed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much! i'll try to do the boolean and see if it works for me!